# React Native Version Mismatch even though the package.json has the right version

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo, version

I am developing an expo app with react native. However I suddenly started encountering the following error [ check print ]

"React Native version mismatch.

JavaScript version: 0.63.3

Native version: 0.64.2"

This error however doesn't appear on my console, only on the emulator.

This is my packge.json file

```
{
"main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
"scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "eject": "expo eject",
    "test": "jest --watchAll",
    "updateAppSyncLayer": "amplify api gql-compile && amplify codegen && babel src/graphql --extensions \".ts\" --config-file ./compile.babel.config.json -d ./amplify/backend/function/outgoingappawsgraphqlQueriesLayer/opt/graphql/"
},
"jest": {
    "preset": "jest-expo"
},
"dependencies": {
    "@aws-amplify/core": "^4.2.9",
    "@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.15.0",
    "@expo-google-fonts/montserrat": "^0.1.0",
    "@expo/vector-icons": "^12.0.0",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "~1.15.0",
    "@react-native-community/datetimepicker": "3.5.2",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "0.1.10",
    "@react-native-community/netinfo": "6.0.2",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^5.11.1",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^5.8.9",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.12.6",
    "@types/react-native-autocomplete-input": "^5.0.0",
    "@types/react-native-check-box": "^2.1.2",
    "@types/react-native-datepicker": "^1.7.1",
    "@types/react-native-read-more-text": "^1.0.0",
    "@types/uuid": "^8.3.1",
    "aws-amplify": "^4.2.9",
    "aws-amplify-react-native": "^5.0.3",
    "expo": "^43.0.0",
    "expo-app-loading": "~1.2.1",
    "expo-barcode-scanner": "~11.1.2",
    "expo-contacts": "~10.0.3",
    "formik": "^2.2.6",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "react": "17.0.1",
    "react-native": "0.63.3",
    "react-native-autocomplete-dropdown": "^1.1.4",
    "react-native-autocomplete-input": "^5.0.2",
    "react-native-check-box": "^2.1.7",
    "react-native-datepicker": "^1.7.2",
    "react-native-dropdown-picker": "^5.1.21",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~1.10.2",
    "react-native-multiple-select": "^0.5.7",
    "react-native-paper": "^4.8.1",
    "react-native-phone-number-input": "^2.1.0",
    "react-native-qrcode-svg": "^6.1.1",
    "react-native-read-more-text": "^1.1.2",
    "react-native-safe-area": "^0.5.1",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^3.3.2",
    "react-native-safe-area-view": "^1.1.1",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.8.0",
    "react-native-svg": "12.1.1",
    "uuid": "^8.3.2",
    "yup": "^0.32.9"
},
"devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.15.4",
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.15.6",
    "@types/react": "~17.0.21",
    "@types/react-native": "0.63.3",
    "jest-expo": "^43.0.0",
    "typescript": "~4.3.5"
},
"private": true
```

}

As you can see I have already set my react-native package to 0.63.3, uninstalled and reinstalled node-modules but I still get the error message.

What can I do?

[image]

Comment: execute `killall node` in your terminal. And then execute your code.

Comment: I have the same problem. It's a head scratcher.